# iPhone X will not boot, possible to data from flash memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-recovery, damage, flash-memory

I have an iphone X that suddenly decided to stop booting. It was getting full and I was trying to delete some photos and videos to free up space when suddenly it wouldn't let me delete any files. I decided to restart the phone and now it won't fully boot up and my MacBook won't recognize the phone when I plug it in. The phone, when I try to start it up, will briefly show the apple logo, but does not boot. I took it to the apple store and they suggested that the motherboard might have a problem.

Is there any way I can extract my photos and videos from the flash memory inside the phone? I've seen a video where someone [extracts a flash memory chip from an iphone and uses it as a USB drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqWLSK2lgsI), but he doesn't bother recovering data. In another video, this same person also is able to [recover data by removing CPU, EEPROM, and flash memory and install these in a new phone to recover data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58-7cg9cYNY), but this looks like a real pain.

Does anyone know if there's a way to interface with the phone like an external drive just to pull the photos off? The fact that it shows the apple logo briefly suggests that the screen is fine and that it's able to at least partially load some firmware. I'd very much like to get a few of these photos as they feature a now-deceased family member.

Comment: Did you ever back up the phone? Any sharing with apple id to the cloud?

Comment: @SolarMike i declined to use iCloud because the volume of photos was such that it was going to get expensive. I had the phone set up to sync automatically via wifi, so it was presumably backed up to my laptop whenever the OS was updated? Is there some way to check if the photos were stored in a backup?